# Salesforce Connector breaks when Logic App is deployed via Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template

I have a Logic App that I developed in the Azure Portal and parameterized it using the parameter tab in the UI. The LA uses connectors for Salesforce, Common Data Service and Service Bus, which were created manually. I have downloaded the Logic App and the parameter file using the Powershell script, and when I try to re-deploy the LA the SF connector fails, the connection for the API shows invalid. From my troubleshooting I figured out that when I try to re-deploy via Visual Studio the ARM template tries to create a new SF connection and fails at the authorization step.
We have other LAs that have SF connections and Visual Studio deployment for them goes fine. I am having issue in the LA that was downloaded via Powershell script and now trying to re-deploy via Visual Studio. I am not sure what is in the template that is triggering the LA Arm Template to create new SF connection.

Below is my LA.json script's resource section and parameter section

```
"resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows",
      "apiVersion": "2019-05-01",
      "name": "[parameters('logicAppName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('logicAppLocation')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections', parameters('salesforce-3_name'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "definition": {
          "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
          "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
              "defaultValue": {},
              "type": "Object"
            }
          },
          "triggers": {
            "When_a_record_is_modified": {
              "recurrence": {
                "frequency": "[parameters('When_a_record_is_modifiedFrequency')]",
                "interval": "[parameters('When_a_record_is_modifiedInterval')]"
              },
              "splitOn": "@triggerBody()?['value']",
              "type": "ApiConnection",
              "inputs": {
                "host": {
                  "connection": {
                    "name": "@parameters('$connections')['salesforce_1']['connectionId']"
                  }
                },
                "method": "get",
                "path": "/datasets/default/tables/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('Account'))}/onupdateditems"
              }
            }
          },
          "actions": {},
          "outputs": {}
        },
        "parameters": {
          "$connections": {
            "value": {
              "salesforce_1": {
                "id": "[concat('/subscriptions/',subscription().subscriptionId,'/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/',parameters('logicAppLocation'),'/managedApis/salesforce')]",
                "connectionId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections', parameters('salesforce-3_name'))]",
                "connectionName": "[parameters('salesforce-3_name')]"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "[parameters('displayName_Tag')]"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
      "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
      "location": "[parameters('logicAppLocation')]",
      "name": "[parameters('salesforce-3_name')]",
      "properties": {
        "api": {
          "id": "[concat('/subscriptions/',subscription().subscriptionId,'/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/',parameters('logicAppLocation'),'/managedApis/salesforce')]"
        },
        "displayName": "[parameters('salesforce-3_displayName')]",
        "parameterValues": {
          "token:LoginUri": "[parameters('salesforce-3_token:LoginUri')]",
          "salesforceApiVersion": "[parameters('salesforce-3_salesforceApiVersion')]"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
```

Below is the parameter file code:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "logicAppName": {
      "value": "param-dynamicexpression"
    },
    "When_a_record_is_modifiedFrequency": {
      "value": "Month"
    },
    "When_a_record_is_modifiedInterval": {
      "value": 3
    },
    "displayName_Tag": {
      "value": "LogicApp"
    },
    "salesforce-3_name": {
      "value": "salesforce-3"
    },
    "salesforce-3_displayName": {
      "value": "Salesforce"
    },
    "salesforce-3_token:LoginUri": {
      "value": "https://test.salesforce.com"
    },
    "salesforce-3_salesforceApiVersion": {
      "value": "v50"
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried to remove the loginurl link, tried updating the parameter but nothing seems to work. Everytime after deployment the connection that was fine earlier breaks. I have been stuck on this for last 2 days, any help or tips is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. I have a logic app with salesforce and service bus actions as shown below,
   [image]

2.I have run below power shell command in azure,

**Export-AzResourceGroup -ResourceGroupName demogroup**

**Note**: I have only logic app in Resource group.

3. The output of above step is,
   [image]
4. Click on Upload/Download files as shown below,
   [image]
5. Give name of the json file from step no 3 as shown below,

[image]

6. Logic app json file will be downloaded to local system.

7.Next created a new project of type Azure resource group then I have edited logicapp.json & logic app parameters file based on template.

8.Then deployed using Deploy option in visual studio and deployment successful.
[image]

9. **LogicApp.json** file code,

```
{

"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
"workflows_deployapp_name": {
"type": "String"
 },
"connections_salesforce_externalid": {
"type": "String"
 },
"connections_servicebus_externalid": {
"type": "String"
 }
},
"variables": {},
"resources": [
{
"type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows",
"apiVersion": "2017-07-01",
"name": "[parameters('workflows_deployapp_name')]",
"location": "centralus",
"properties": {
"state": "Enabled",
"definition": {
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
"$connections": {
"defaultValue": {},
"type": "Object"
  }
},
"triggers": {
"manual": {
"type": "Request",
"kind": "Http",
"inputs": {}
 }
},
"actions": {
"For_each": {
"foreach": "@body('Get_records')?['value']",
"actions": {
"Compose": {
"runAfter": {},
"type": "Compose",
"inputs": {
"Account Name": "@items('For_each')?['Name']",
"Billing Street": "@items('For_each')?['BillingStreet']"
  }
},
"Send_message": {
"runAfter": {
"Compose": [
"Succeeded"
 ]
},
"type": "ApiConnection",
"inputs": {
"body": {
"ContentData": "@{base64(outputs('Compose'))}"
},
"host": {
"connection": {
"name": "@parameters('$connections')['servicebus']['connectionId']"
 }
},
"method": "post",
"path": "/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('sbqu01'))}/messages",
"queries": {
"systemProperties": "None"
   }
  }
}
},
"runAfter": {
"Get_records": [
"Succeeded"
 ]
},

"type": "Foreach"
},
"Get_records": {
"runAfter": {},
"type": "ApiConnection",
"inputs": {
"host": {
"connection": {
"name": "@parameters('$connections')['salesforce']['connectionId']"
  }
},
"method": "get",
"path": "/datasets/default/tables/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('Account'))}/items"
   }
  }
},
"outputs": {}
},
"parameters": {
"$connections": {
"value": {
"salesforce": {
"connectionId": "[parameters('connections_salesforce_externalid')]",
"connectionName": "salesforce",
"id": "/subscriptions/<yoursubscriptionid>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/centralus/managedApis/salesforce"
},
"servicebus": {
"connectionId": "[parameters('connections_servicebus_externalid')]",
"connectionName": "servicebus",
"id": "/subscriptions/<yoursubscriptionid>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/centralus/managedApis/servicebus"

       }
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

10. **LogicApp.parameters.json** file code,

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
"workflows_deployapp_name": {
"value": "lapp01"
},
"connections_salesforce_externalid": {
"value": "/subscriptions/<yoursubscriptionid>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/centralus/managedApis/salesforce"
},
"connections_servicebus_externalid": {
"value": "/subscriptions/<yoursubscriptionid>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/centralus/managedApis/servicebus"
    }
  }
 }
```

11. Designer of deployed logic app from visual studio is,
    [image]

12.Tested logic app and it is running successfully,
[image]